# Compilation issue when class (compiled with java 5) talks to another class (compiled in java 6)

Tags: java-6, java-5

If a java project compiled with jdk 5 talks to another project which is compiled with jdk 6, whether it leads to any compilation issue(s)?. In simple, can a lower version of java talks to higher version of java give any compilation error? Any clarifications would be appreciable.

Thanks,
Marshal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. Go right ahead. We all depend on it every day.